# I have a virtual destructor and an array in my base class. How can I make it work?

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

Ex:

```
class base
{
public:
  base()
  {
    // allocate memory for basearray
  }
  virtual ~base()
  {
    // delete basearray
  }

protected:
  float* basearray;
};

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
  derived1()
  {
    // allocate memory for derivedarray
  }
  ~derived1()
  {
    // delete derived array
  }

protect:
  float* derivedarray;
};

void main()
{
  derived1 d;

  ...

  base* pb = &d;

  ...

  // Delete base array? 
}
```

I have a virtual destructor and an array in my base class. If the base class destructor is overridden by the derived class destructor, then the basearray won't get deleted. What's a nice solution?

Comment: You should be able to call parent destructor via `base::~base();` in delivered destructor

Comment: @Vyktor: Calling the Base class destructor manually would defeat the whole purpose of making Base class destructor virtual. No?

Comment: @Vyktor: Do NOT EVER call a destructor manually, unless you really really know what you are doing. There is aproximately one case, where it is correct to manually call the destructor and this case is very rare, unless you are dealing with severe memory constraints.

Comment: Even if not virtual the base class destructor would get called.

Comment: virtual is to make sure the derived class destructor gets called.

Comment: @LiKao can you be more specific (I'm here to learn something, not to argue and I want more information)?

Comment: @Vyktor: The cases where you need to explicetly call the destructor are very rare. Details about this have to do with advanced features of memory handling in C++ and should only be attempted after one has a very good handling of other C++ features. One of these rare cases is embeded systems design in C++ where a normal `new` and `delete` cannot be used and you still want to use objects (look up placement new). The normal case is to let the compiler call the destructors automatically, because it will do a much better job than manuall handling of destruction. Hence this is the way to go.

Comment: @Vyktor: See what happens in the code I linked to at ideone. In the output you can see, that both the `base` destructor as well as the `derived` destructor are called. It is important to know that virtual means something fundamentally different in the context of a destructor than when it appears in a normal method and has hardly anything to do with overriding. A virtual destructor means, that all destructors of the hierarchy get called in a well defined order. If the virtual is left out, the hierarchy is only used from the current state upward and derived destructors may be missed.

Comment: @LiKao thanks for detailed explanation and answer (+1). I'm using php most of the time and you easily forget those things when they're different in what you're working with.

Comment: @user - See that the others have missed the obligatory: Don't allocate arrays yourself, use a `std::vector`. It does all the work for you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base-class destructor **is** automatically called, right after the derived-class destructor has run.

Answer (score 2):

When destructing a derived object and the destructor of the base is virtual, both destructors will be called. You can confirm this here: http://ideone.com/RZamr

The order will be opposite to the order of constructors, i.e. when constructing first a constructor of `base` will be called, then on of `derived`. When destructing first the destructor of `derived` will be called, then the one of `base`.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual destructors don't work the same way that other virtual functions do in that a base class's virtual destructor is never overridden.  Instead, when a subclass provides their own destructor, that subclass destructor fires, then the base class destructor fires as well.  The "virtual" here is used so that if you delete a derived class object through a base class pointer, C++ knows to call the destructor based on the dynamic type of the object (the subclass) rather than the static type of the pointer (the superclass).  As a result, you don't need to do anything special here. The base class destructor will work as usual.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When overriding a destructor the base class destructor is still called as long as it is defined as 'virtual', which is what you have done.

So in this example:

```
  class base
  {
  public:
     base()
     {
        myarray = new float[100];
     }

     ~base()
     {
        delete[] myarray;
     }

  private:
     float* myarray;
  }


  class derived : public base
  {
  public:
     derived()
     {
     }

     ~derived()
     {
     }
  }
```

This will not delete 'myarray' and will leak memory because the base class destructor is hidden by the derived class destructor. However:

```
  class base
  {
  public:
     base()
     {
        myarray = new float[100];
     }

     virtual ~base()
     {
        delete[] myarray;
     }

  private:
     float* myarray;
  }


  class derived : public base
  {
  public:
     derived()
     {
     }

     ~derived()
     {
     }
  }
```

This will delete the array.

Bear in mind that constructors are called from the base class up, so the base class constructor is called first, followed by the derived class, whereas destructors are called in the reverse order, so your derived class destructor is called before that of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem here.  The base class destructor is called right after the derived class destructor is called.

There's only one circumstance where this is not true: delete is called on a pointer to the base class where the base class destructor is *not* virtual.

In all circumstances where you have a local instance of a class, created on the stack, and the function or method exits, even because of an exception, the instance is correctly destructed.

In all circumstances where an instance of a class is `new`d, and subsequently deleted through a pointer to the exact class that was instantiated, the instance is correctly destructed.

When an instance of a class is `new`d, but deleted through a base class pointer, the instance is only correctly destructed when the base class has a virtual destructor (either declared `virtual` itself or its own base has a virtual destructor), the instance is correctly destructed.